# why can't I get the 2nd item, including the zeroth from my list

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

`my_list   = ["a", 1.3, True, 17, "b", "c", 6.02214076e23, False]`

I am trying to write a code to get the 2nd term including the Xero term,and I've tried this code:

```
my_list[::2]
print(my_list)
```

but the code is still returning as

```
my list:
['a', 1.3, True, 17, 'b', 'c', 6.02214076e+23, False]
```

the code I tried

```
my_list[::2]
print(my_list)
```

but it's still giving me a copy of the full list again:
`['a', 1.3, True, 17, 'b', 'c', 6.02214076e+23, False]`

Comment: The slice doesn't change the list, you have to assign it to something.

Comment: Doesn't ```6.02214076e23``` need to be a String?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman No, that's a perfectly fine floating point literal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression does not modify the list. You can fix this by assigning the output value back to a variable:

```py
res = my_list[:2]

print(res)
```

Comment: sorry I meant I want to get every other 2nd term from the list including the 0th term.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing does not modify the list. Assign the slice to another variable or reassign the result back to `my_list`.

```py
res = my_list[::2]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ans:

```
my_list   = ["a", 1.3, True, 17, "b", "c", 6.02214076e23, False]
print(my_list[::2])
```

Output:

```
['a', True, 'b', 6.02214076e+23]
```